# get an array for each year

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli, highcharts

DB table holds numeric data, 12 set (jan-dec) for each year.
I need an array with all data for each year...

example of DB "web_table"

```
2009 jan 10
2009 feb 66
...
2015 jan 99
```

I need to use the output array in Highchart series. One array for each year.

```
series: [{
    name: '2009',
    type: 'spline',
    data: [<?php echo $the_array_for_2009;?>] //outcome: data: [10,66,..,..]
},{
    name: '2010',
    ..etc..
```

Today i'm querying each and every year with is very undynamic:

```
$str2009 = "SELECT * FROM web_table WHERE year = 2009";
... (etc)
$str2015 = "SELECT * FROM web_table WHERE year = 2015";
```

Help me with a foreach() and loop the whole "series settings" solution or any other suggestions?

Comment: and what have you tried so far?

Comment: So what problem are you actually having with your code? If you show the code and explain what isn't working, then we might be able to help

Comment: Today i'm running one query for 2009, one for 2010, one for 2011.... (join($data2009, ',')) which obviously gave me problem over new year since i then had to go in and add a new query for 2015...

Comment: Yeah, I don't get this question. One array for each year... ok... eh? Something like `SELECT * FROM web_table WHERE year = ?` perhaps?

Comment: What i'm doing today for each year - but very un dynamic (described above)@KIKOSoftware...

Comment: Try `date('Y')` to get the current year. Then do a for loop from whatever year you start till this year.

Comment: I need more of a foreach solution with possibility to loop the whole source with each year

Comment: Well you need an array for that. You could so something like: `SELECT year, GROUP_CONCAT(score SEPARATOR ',') FROM web_table GROUP BY year` and use the resulting array.

Comment: Alright - i'll try that. (post an answer...) @KIKOSoftware Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, your question is to vague for a real answer. What DB interface are you using? What are the column names? Where's your example code?

Comment: Why the hell did someone down-vote this question? It might be a simple solution but if you'r stucked, you are.

Comment: Questions here should serve two purposes: 1. So you get your question answered. 2. So other people might learn from your question and the answers. Since it's very difficult to answer your question, it's very incomplete, you've disregarded the second point. That might have given you the downvote.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the explanation @KIKOSoftware! I've edited the question "So other people might learn from your question and the answers" =)

Comment: Yes, much better. :-) I will guess a column name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM web_table WHERE year = 2009";
```

you could do:

```
$query = "SELECT year, GROUP_CONCAT(score SEPARATOR ',') AS data 
          FROM web_table 
          GROUP BY year";
```

Here 'score' contains the column you want to put in the array under the key 'data'.

Once you have this you can do:

```
if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
  foreach($result->fetch_all() as $row) {
    $series[] = array('year' => $row['year'],
                      'type' => 'spline',
                      'data' => $row['data']);
  } 
  $result->close();
}
```

Comment: Brilliant! Had to add `MYSQLI_ASSOC`...  `foreach($result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC) as $row)`to get the values. Will you please show me how you place the $series[] into the "series"-script (highchart)...

Comment: Ah, yeah, it must be associative. I forgot that. I must assume 'highchart' is some kind of package to make graphs? Sorry, I don't know the first thing about that. I just made $series[] after your example.

Answer (score 0):

This not the most elegant code, but should get you somewhere, Its all PHP and you could probably do something nicer in pure SQL.

```
<?php
// This be your mysql response
$data = [
    [2009, 'jan', 10],
    [2009, 'feb', 66],
    [2015, 'jan', 99],
];

$newdata = [];
foreach($data as $d) {
    $newdata[$d[0]][$d[1]] = $d[2];
}

$charts = [];
foreach($newdata as $year => $results) {
     $charts[] = "{ name: $year, type: 'spline', data: [ ". implode(',', $results) ." ] }";
}

echo 'Series: [' . implode(',', $charts) .'];';
```

Example output:

> Series: [{ name: 2009, type: 'spline', data: [ 10,66 ] },{ name: 2015, type: 'spline', data: [ 99 ] }];